# State sharing architecture - how to enable rolling policy?

Tags: algorithm, apache-kafka, architecture

**Scenario**: Kafka stream provides stream of events where each event  is a record that has to be processed **after aggregating 1000 records**(rolling policy). To give background, Each record provide SMS usage details of a  mobile network for a specific mobile phone user. Processing of each record will map one-on-one downstream record(for *usage billing*, *tax calculation*, *usage validity* etc...). There are multiple downstreams.

**Goal**: File of 1000 records generated(for each down stream) should have correlation, after processing 1000 records(received as kafka events) . Correlation mean, say, if file generated for *usage billing*  downstream has 100 records(100 specific users) then file generated for *tax calculation* should also have same sequence of records(same 100 specific users).This is the ask.

---

**Problem is**, if we process records by directly reading kafka events then file correlation is not being ensured, as we are unable to perform aggregation logic consistently

---

Every record is crucial for the business and cannot be missed(from processing). Processing app will be deployed in kubernetes cluster. Each record is structured with column(field) names

How to ensure correlation of records in downstream files? Is it by setting rolling policy of records before processing? If yes, to ensure rolling policy, Do we need to store kafka events in some file(kubernetes PVC) or database(as intermediate state) and then process the records?

Comment: You say, "if we process records by directly reading kafka events then file correlation is not being ensured, as we are unable to perform aggregation logic consistently."  Why not? There doesn't need to be any uncertainty or non-determinism in how consumers aggregate records.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why files are necessary at all? If Uber can use Kafka for trip/payment information on single events without missing any, then you should be able to as well? You could use Kafka Streams to create a tumbling window of data before processing in chunks, but writing files seems like you'd fill up disk fast, with a loss of fault tolerance that Kafka provides (what if kubernetes restarts your app before you read any written file)

Comment: @OneCricketeer let's say, I have one processing pipeline for each downstream and each pipeline read records from same Kafka stream.... does  tumbling window in pipeline one will ensure same aggregation of records compared to tumbling window of pipeline two? If yes, Can you provide some reference to GoLang based implementation for tumbling window

Comment: @OneCricketeer we have to specify tumbling window with size of 15 mins. But tumbling window in pipeline One may not aggregate records same as tumbling window in pipeline two

Comment: @MattTimmermans there is uncertainty in aggregation because  consumer pipeline one(for down stream one) perform aggregation which is different from consumer pipeline two(for downstream two)

Comment: I think you're making assumptions about Kafka that aren't true, and I'm trying to get you to state them.

Comment: @MattTimmermans 1) when consumer pipelineOne  and pipelineTwo read the records from same  Kafka stream and aggregate data based on tumbling window(must be time size in our scenario), then, the aggregation of records within across pipelines cannot be same 2) are you suggesting to maintain intermediate state in another  Kafka topic? Which assumptions are you referring to? I didn't get you

Comment: I think Apache Beam has a Go SDK that can do this, but otherwise Kafka Streams is really the only option for built in SDK for tumbling/sliding time windows. But, yes, consuming the exact same data with the same pipeline operators (a different consumer group) should operate the same way, since Kafka is durable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Kafka topic is divided into partitions.  Within each partition, the messages are strictly ordered, and sequentially numbered with an offset.  In addition, each message is given a timestamp.

The Kafka API lets you read each partition from any offset, so if you just define a consistent strategy for aggregating these messages, then each of your consumers can implement the same strategy and all of their aggregations will be the same.

For example, let's say you decide that, for each partition, you will aggregate every block of 1000 messages with offsets between n*1000 and (n+1)*1000.  This is probably the simplest strategy that works.  Now each of your downstream consumers can implement this strategy.  Since they all see the same messages with the same offsets in the same partitions, in the same order, they will all perform the same aggregations.

Comment: For consumers to read same offset, from same partition... Does all consumers need to have different consumer id? How to ensure each consumer read from same offset from same partition?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)

Comment: And yes, each downstream processor should be in a different consumer group

Comment: When should we commit to Kafka that offset has been consumed successfully? because downstream processor may fail or crash in kubernetes

Comment: When a downstream processor has completed an aggregation and *durably* recorded the results, then it can commit the offset after that aggregation.

Comment: Are you saying that, consume with offset and then commit after processing will ensure  consistent aggregation?